# How to extract a fragment that can appear multiple times in a string

Tags: python, regex

I have emails which have following in email body (from email_body variable)  :

[body](https://1drv.ms/t/s!AizscpxS0QM4hKAQ7EcctDVc6vo9kw) for 1st email:

[2.email:](https://1drv.ms/t/s!AizscpxS0QM4hKARmY6eRHuvCX8JCg)

3 email:

same as for 2 just different machine name

These emails have attachments which also have job names, i want to get job name for every email only once

```
for emailid in items:
    resp, data = conn.uid("fetch",emailid, "(RFC822)")
    if resp == 'OK':
        email_body = data[0][1].decode('utf-8')
        mail = email.message_from_string(email_body)
        #get all emails with words "PA1" or "PA2" in subject
        if mail["Subject"].find("PA1") > 0 or mail["Subject"].find("PA2") > 0:
                  #search email body for machine name (string after word "MACHINE")
          regex1 = r'(?<!^)MACHINE:\s*(\S+)'

          a=re.findall(regex1 ,email_body)
          print (c)
```

example of message body from 1st email for MACHINE section retrived from python code, it's email_body variable which needs to be searched by regex:

```
MACHINE: =^M
example_machine_1
```

Email body for 2nd email

```
MACHINE: example_machine_2^M
MACHINE: example_machine_2<br>^M
```

The difference is in line break in 1st email body

**Current output**

```
['example_machine_1', 'example_machine_1<br>']
['example_machine_2', 'example_machine_2<br>']
['=', '=']
```

as you can see, i'm getting duplicate jobs and missing job name from 1st email

**Desired output**

```
['example_machine_3']
['example_machine_2']
['example_machine_1']
```

**UPDATE**

Thanks to @Predicate i eliminated duplicates for 2nd and 3rd email

```
regex2 = r'(?<=MACHINE: )\b\w+\b|$'
```

still have no idea how to get job from first email (line break)

Comment: Post the expected matches that you want

Comment: Try this [`(?<=MACHINE: )\S*`](https://regex101.com/r/IYj8zG/2)

Comment: nope,same output

Comment: It matches in the link I provided. Also, if you want to see the code, click [HERE](https://regex101.com/r/IYj8zG/2/codegen?language=python)

Comment: just added example from email body

Comment: Do you mean like this? https://regex101.com/r/IyU5m9/1

Comment: this is what i get:`['p2prog06\r', 'p2prog06']['p1prog06\r', 'p1prog06']
['\r']`

Comment: So you have 3 email bodies where you want to find what comes after `MACHINE:`.
How does `MACHINE: =^M
ldnmdsbatchxl01` relate to the messages at the top? In which text do you want to find what match?

Comment: `MACHINE: =^M ldnmdsbatchxl01` is email body i get when printing email_body variable to text file. First text is seen  from email client and second from python code, i need to search second text (from email_body variable-it contains whole email) and i need only first match.(Email body contains multiple MACHINE names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this one. With defined word boundaries. `\w` matches letter, digits and underscores. `\b` marks a word boundary. `\b` does not match `<` so it will end before the `<br>` tag.

Try to be as specific as you can. If you know what characters will be used in your match than use them in your regex. It will reduce the amount of false positive and also boost the speed of the search.

**Variant 1:**

```
regex1 = r'(?<=MACHINE: )\b\w+\b'
```

**Variant 2:**

Also possible (if the codes are in the format `<some letters and digits>< two digits>`). To be more specific:

```
regex1 = r'(?<=MACHINE: )\b\w+\d{2}\b'
```

**Variant 3:**

If there are multiple appearances of the same code - one way to handle it is matching only the last appearance of the job name. We will create a capturing group `(\w+\d{2})` and will check that it will not appear after it was matched `(?!.*\1)`:

```
regex1 = r'(?<=MACHINE: )\b(\w+\d{2})\b(?!.*\1)'
```

**Variant 4 (after getting more info about the environment):**

're' module does not support varying length lookbehinds. It is better to use regex from pypi, but you can use this trick. Try it.

```
regex1 = r'(?<=MACHINE:\s=\s|..MACHINE:\s)\b(\w+)\b(?!.*\1)'
```

matches both emails and only once. [one](https://regex101.com/r/K0gaBI/4/) [two](https://regex101.com/r/zpdiU0/4/)

Of course you can still be more specific if you know the structure of your codes and replace `\w+` with `\w+\d{2}`. Its always a good practise. But my regex should be enough for you. Also you would probably need to compile the regex with "single line flag".  `regex1 = re.compile(r'<your regex>',  re.DOTALL)` and do then `regex1.findall(...`

Comment: still missing MACHINE Name from 1st email (ldnmdsbatchxl01) and returned values are duplicated:`['p2prog06', 'p2prog06']
[]` name from 1st email is in new line

Comment: the you are not giving us the full information. Because there are not dublicates in the email you gavbe us. https://regex101.com/r/zetdDc/1

Comment: https://1drv.ms/t/s!AizscpxS0QM4hKAQ7EcctDVc6vo9kw this is example of email with returns no data

Comment: Yes , thats because there is a line break between the MAchine and the job name. You provided us examples without this informations.

Comment: I specified it in section above Current output" :)

Comment: Yes, and the provided us with not valid test data. It is contradicting. Do not do that. Help us to help you.

Comment: And also youre new test data hase this format: "MACHINE: = <CODE>", in the question you mentioned only "MACHINE: <CODE>". That is why you are matching "="

Comment: Sorry for confusion caused, yes i noticed difference in email body, just uploaded data for second email nody, for 3rd it's the same as for 2nd, thanks for your help

Comment: using the pypi regex module would be easier. Because the re module only  support lookbehinds of fixed length

Comment: Oh, have no idea how to use it

Comment: Thanks a lot @Predicate. this finally works: `regex2 = r'\bMACHINE:\s*(?:=.*)?\s*([^<^\n ]+)|$' re.findall(regex2, email_body)[0]`